# Problem with Three20 TTPhotoViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask or report this... but i hope someone here can help me out with the following problem

I'm currently creating an app which offers several functionalities. anyways it also includes the TTPhotoViewController which Three20 offers. Well this controller is absolutely awesome but i'm having some trouble after using the TTPhotoviewcontorller, since then all content falls behind my navigationbarcontroller.

Here are some screenshots where you can see before and after opening the viewcontroller

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[After http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/5899/foto1c.jpg](http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/5899/foto1c.jpg)

Hopefully you guys can help me out since i'm quite new in these things.

Thanks in advance,
Wesley

Answer (score 7):

I guess what causes the problem is that the TTPhotoviewcontorller changes the bar style of the navigation bar of your navigation controller to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent, and what you need to do is to reset the bar style property to UIBarStyleDefault. You may try to call:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
```

in the viewDidAppear: method of your view controller in the screenshots.

BTW, if your view controller is a subclass of TTViewController, you may try to apply the navigationBarStyle property.

Comment: I had the same trouble as @Coppes, and your solution worked beautifully, except that instead of navigationBar.bar you meant navigationBar.barStyle.

Comment: @zonble you saved my day, thanks! Small enhancement, its better to be added inside viewWillAppear to avoid changing the style in front of the user

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best result is to set:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle
```

to `UIBarStyleDefault` (or `UIBarStyleBlack`)

in the `viewWillAppear` method of the viewController that will appear after dismissing the `TTPhotoviewcontorller`.

`viewDidAppear` will work to, though it might cause some 'jumping' visual effect in the view.